# Django : intercept authentication to store session variable or cookie

Tags: django, authentication

I am working on a project that's running on django.  I would like to authenticate in multiple places.  First, I would like to maintain the standard authentication mechanism and continue using it for site administration.  Second, I would like to intercept the login request in addition to the standard authentication, and check if the user has is authenticated on another system and store a session variable or cookie to be used later if authenticated.  Then on logout remove the session variable or cookie.  The second authentication mechanism should not affect the first.  In addition, if the first succeeds and the second fails, it should have no affect on the standard administration.

I have looked into declaring a custom authentication backend in the settings AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS tuple.  But from what I understand, it authenticates in order and will stop authenticating once a match is made.

Any guidance in regards to this would be most appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is set and unset cookie or session var you can use signals sent by authentication module ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals))

Example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in, user_logged_out

def user_logged_in_hook(sender, **kwargs):
    # kwargs will contain request and user objects
    print kwargs


def user_logged_out_hook(sender, **kwargs):
    # kwargs will contain request and user objects
    print kwargs


user_logged_in.connect(user_logged_in_hook)
user_logged_out.connect(user_logged_out_hook)
```